# Squid Transparent Proxy with port 80 redirection: blank page for some sites

Tags: squid, port, redirection

I have a squid transparent proxy that's working great.

To save time on client configurations I've decided to redirect port 80 to 3128 so I can configure for all clients the new proxy just changing gateway in dhcp server.
It went well, I've used this rule:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128`

Now I can surf the internet from clients without problems but it seems I can't open some websites, like gmail.

It loads for ages and then I get a blank page.

If I set manually proxy values in the browser it works without problems.
Using port redirection work for some sites but won't work for others...

What's wrong?

edit:

Reading here and there I see that is a common problem solved in various (and difficult) ways like this: http://www.rahulpahade.com/content/squid-transparent-proxy-over-ssl-https

I'd need simple commands so let https traffic go straight to the internet...
How can I achieve this?

Comment: It seems that your problem is related to https traffic (you mentioned gmail). Is the public IP of proxy server the same as your clients (same NATing)?

Answer (score 1):

What about packets that leave your LAN through other ports? Are you dropping them?

If yes, I believe you also need to redirect the packets that go through port 443 (https) to the proxy or accept them before you drop the rest.

> > **Also redirect https to the proxy**: iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dports 80,443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
> >
> > **HTTPs going straight to the internet**: Before your redirect rule, add this:
> >     -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j [RETURN or ACCEPT (choosing between return and accept will depend on the rest of your firewall)].

In case you've done that already, try to check the squid logs to see what they say.

Finally, it'd be of great help if you post your all your rules here.